# Time Series analysis with R, how to deal with daily data

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I try to convert a daily dataset to `ts`, but how do you deal with leap year? so what value should I set the frequency equal to?

`ts(data,start=c(2010,1,1),frequency=365)?`

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437620/analyzing-daily-weekly-data-using-ts-in-r/8438069#8438069

Comment: Little misconception here: for `?ts`, R gives ***"start - the time of the first observation. Either a single number or a vector of two integers"***. What you are trying to do (give a YMD date) is unknown to the ts function.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the packages [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) or [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) (which relies on `zoo`). With these time formats you can define the time series with or without daylight saving times or leap years.

Additionally I would suggest using the package [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) to do timespan calculations. `lubridate` makes a difference between periods and durations.

The **duration** class measures the exact time span between two moments in time, that you would measure on a stop watch.

In contrast a **period** is for example "a month". But how long is a month? Depends on which month you mean. And for example in leap years month february has a different duration, but same period length.

Whether you need the duration or the period depends on your subject and objective. With `zoo` and `lubridate` you can choose the one that is relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with frequency for leap year, set frequency as given below:

```
date=c(2010,1,1)

ts(data,start=date,frequency=365+1* (!date[1]%%400 || ((date[1]%%100)&&!date[1]%%4) ))?
```

Answer (score 0):

frequency can set to 365.25 to include leap year

```
ts(data,start=c(2010,1,1),frequency=365.25)
```