# weekly time series in r, arima

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a data frame with the following column names.

```
"week" "demand" "product-id"
```

The problem is to convert it into a time series object.

`week` is a number like 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc., and `demand` is in units and `product-id` is unique.

I want to convert the week column into time series, so as to prepare for modeling.

I want to predict weeks 10 and 11 demand by using an ARIMA model. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a MCVE with questions regarding how to write code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and please take care to use proper capitalization, grammar, and formatting in your questions. I've made some improvements to the question but please provide sample data and code to represent what you've done thusfar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTS <- ts(mydataframe[-1], frequency = 52)
```

will convert your `demand` and `productId` to a timeseries of 52 observations per year. For more elaborate timeseries, check package [xts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html). Also compare [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437620/analyzing-daily-weekly-data-using-ts-in-r) on weekly data with `ts`.

Comment: Thank you for replying promptly. what do i do if i have some missing weeks.ie., @week is 3,6,7,8 etc .. with missing values

Comment: That depends on what you want the values to be: NA? An interpolation of neighboring values? Last observation carried forward? One way would be to create a list of `week` values, like so: `wks <- rep(seq(1, 52), numberOfYears)`, then [`dplyr::left_join(wks, mydataframe)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html) to create a list including missing weeks. Then choose some function like [`zoo::na.locf`](http://search.r-project.org/library/zoo/html/na.locf.html) to fill the missing values.

Comment: are you sure that mydataframe[-1] will do the work for me i am expecting that the column with week should be fed to ts() function. as there are three columns as stated in the above problem.

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Do you know what it does and how to call ts()?

Comment: i donot know how ts() function works , i would really appreciate any direction you provide in understanding time series and `ts()` function